# PHP: How can I check which navbar point is active?

Tags: php, menu

I have to check which listpoint in the menu is active and I'd like to know if there's a way in php?

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="a">...</li>
  <li class="b">...</li>
  <li class="c">...</li>
</ul>
```

So how can I check if a is active or b or c, etc. ?

In my example I mean, how can I give the `<li>` which you selected a `class="..."`, but only this one.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You could read the DOM into PHP and select the one with e. g. a class called `active` with an DOM parser, but I doubt that this is what your goal is.

Comment: What do you mean by "active"? You can't read client activity from PHP directly... PHP is only evaluated server-side, and you must use JavaScript to handle client-side activity.

Comment: PHP may be used to an html before sending it to the client, but after you see the webpage would need to use javascript for that purpose. Still it would be good to know what's the content of the li element and why do you need to find an active one. Also you can just add class="active" to an element to find it and perform some action on it.

Comment: no there is not a way, in php.

Answer (score 1):

In a pinch you can get this done with php sessions, simply set a variable any time a menu is switched.

The session variable should be set near the top of whatever page it is being used on, so that way PHP can recognize it before the menu loads on the page.

Here is a small snippet for inspiration, you could do this a lot of different ways.

```
<?
session_start();

if(isSet($_GET['switch'])) {
    $_SESSION['menuPage'] = $_GET['switch'];
}
$menuPage = $_SESSION['menuPage'];

echo $menuPage."<br>";

?>

<ul class="menu">
    <li <? if(strcmp($menuPage,"a") == 0) { echo "active"; } ?> class="a"><a href="?switch=a">A</a></li>
    <li <? if(strcmp($menuPage,"b") == 0) { echo "active"; } ?> class="b"><a href="?switch=b">B</a></li>
    <li <? if(strcmp($menuPage,"c") == 0) { echo "active"; } ?> class="c"><a href="?switch=c">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note: You want to use a session and not a normal variable so that the $_GET for the menu doesn't have to constantly be present in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the `$_SERVER` variable, more specifically `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. This shows you the requested URL. Based on this, you can check which menu item should be active.